# How to change my DB name in a query dynamically, but without exec a string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic

I have many DB in my SQL server, sometimes we put a copy of the QA DB server for test purposes, then I want to have a variable that select a value from a Table that indicates the name of the DB and change in my function, with no need of rewriting the function for changing the name of the DB, or executing a string to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do this without dynamic SQL and you certainly can't do it in a function.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you might be able to do this with a [linked server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx). If your QA server were a linked server on your other DB's server, you could query it using [ServerName].[DbName].[Schema].[Table]. For example: `SELECT * FROM [QAServer].[QADatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]`. If you're not careful, though, this can cause poor performance (or security holes, in some cases)

Comment: I don't get how you expect to change the name of the db in the function but no need of rewriting the function.

Comment: I mean, to do something very generic, rewrite all the functions, but then when I need to switch of db name, there would be no need of change all the functions names of DB.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE SYNONYM Cust FOR DB1.dbo.Customer
GO

SELECT * FROM Cust
GO

DROP SYNONYM Cust
CREATE SYNONYM Cust FOR DB2.dbo.Customer
GO

SELECT * FROM Cust
```

This technique has limitations, but in some cases it is very useful: [MSDN CREATE SYNONYM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx)

Comment: This is neat, I didn't know you could do this. Won't this only work if the two databases are on the same server, though? Or does it also work for linked servers?

Comment: Is a good idea, but my DB has a lot of tables, it could work for some cases, but I'm trying to find a generic solution. (Let me read you link)

Comment: Did you read my link? Remote or locale object: `    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver Server_Remote;
GO
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM MyEmployee FOR Server_Remote.AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee;
GO`

Comment: This could work, I just need a Strategy in the Department to switch beetween DB, and the best is that it will be invisible for the programmers.

Comment: It won't be invisible to the programmers. If you want one programmer to see Cust as DB1.dbo.Customer, and another to see Cust as DB2.dbo.Customer, how do you propose you do that *at the same time*? A synonym can only point to one object at a time, so it may work when you're the only developer, but beyond that you're out of luck...

Comment: Of course @AaronBertrand , we need to create a process in our department so the deployers could manage the switch for one or the the other DB, we have to work in a strategy to make this posible.